# Store Multiple Checkbox values in an array

Tags: javascript

I serialized a form data. In that form, i have checkboxes named "assets".

```
                    <div class="fot-form">
                        <label class="fot-form__label">Select the assets you own</label><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="assets" class="fot-form__check" value="phone">Smartphone<br>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="assets" class="fot-form__check" value="bike">Bike<br>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="assets" class="fot-form__check" value="laptop">Laptop<br>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="assets" class="fot-form__check" value="car">Car<br>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="assets" class="fot-form__check" value="home">Home
                    </div>
```

In JS after below code
var data = $(".test-form").serializeArray();
var testFormJson = *.object(*.pluck(data, 'name'), _.pluck(data, 'value'));

I got only assets:"car", not an array like assets: ["car", "laptop", "phone"]. How to retrieve this array.

Comment: Why not simply naming it `assets[]`? It will form array

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="assets[]">
```

This will form an array of selected items

Comment: In "testFormJson", i got only this data  assets[]:"laptop"

Comment: But in "data", i got object{"name":"assets[]", "value:"bike"}, object{"name":"assets[]", "value:"laptop"}, object{"name":"assets[]", "value:"car"}

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes are not radio buttons. A radio button returns a single name/value pair based on a selection and each option has the same name.  In a checkbox, each option can not share a name="thing" setting as they all refer to the same thing.

There is no magic here: each checkbox is a single element (similar to a multiple select list).  A radio button is way of determining a choice between elements (similar to an input="text").